# C++ - Method Override Isn't Expressed as Expected

Tags: c++, thread-safety, overriding

I have a Base class `Point` (representing a 2D point in space) that is non-thread-safe for move operations; so I defined an inherited class `LockedPoint` that overrides 2 methods in the base class: `moveTo` and `moveBy`:

```
void Point::moveTo(float xPos, float yPos) {
    x = xPos;
    y = yPos;
}

void Point::moveBy(float xOff, float yOff) {
    x += xOff;
    y += yOff;
}

void LockedPoint::moveTo(float xPos, float yPos) {
    MutGuard m(lock);
    x = xPos;
    y = yPos;
}

void LockedPoint::moveBy(float xOff, float yOff) {
    MutGuard m(lock);
    x += xOff;
    y += yOff;
}

( where x and y = private member variables,
    lock = a private mutex, and
    MutGuard = typedef lock_guard<mutex> )
```

To visually see the problem with the "unlocked" `Point`, I wrote up a test routine:

```
void sleepForMS(long ms) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(ms));
}

void messWithPoint(Point& p, int type) {

    float n = 1;
    if (type) n *= -1;

    for (long i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

        p.moveBy(n, n);

        sleepForMS(rand() % (type ? 2 : 3));

        if (i % 500 == 0)
            std::cout << i << ":\t" << p << std::endl;

    }

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using namespace std;

    Point p;

    thread t1(messWithPoint, std::ref(p), 0);

    sleepForMS(33);

    thread t2(messWithPoint, std::ref(p), 1);

    cout << "Started\n";

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    cout << p << endl;
}
```

With a `Point`, the resulting `p` is "corrupted", as expected (it should equal `(0,0)` by the end, and it doesn't). If I change `p` to a `LockedPoint` though, the base version of `moveBy` is still called (verified by print debugging).

I read up on method "overriding" (apparently more correctly called "method hiding"), and from what I understand, if the overriding method has the same signature as the base method, it hides the base version, and is called instead. Why then is the base method being called despite the 2 having the same signature? The only thing I can think of is because I'm specifying `Point` in `messWithPoint`'s argument list, it's taking that literally and calling `Point`'s version. If I change the signature to `void messWithPoint(LockedPoint& p, int type)`, the resulting `LockedPoint` is `(0,0)`, as expected. Shouldn't it "see" that the passed `LockedPoint` overrides the used method, and use the "least hidden" version?

If that's not how it works, is there a way to specify taking the base class, but having it use any available overridden versions?

Comment: You need to specify the methods in the base and sub class are "virtual"

Comment: Hard to tell since you didn't include the definition of `Point`. Are the _member functions_ declared virtual?

Comment: Ya, you guys were right; they need to be virtual in the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member functions are not virtual, so the functions in the class known at compile time are used.

However, for a simple class such as point, using virtual member functions or providing automatic mutual exclusion goes against the C++ idea of not paying for what you don't use.

Just copy points.

Comment: Thank you, that never crossed my mind. And I thought inheritance would be perfect here since I only need to override a couple methods.

Comment: In this situation, the difference seems negligible. A set of non-virtual tests averaged 20.41 seconds. Making it virtual increased the average to 20.44 seconds (99.85% as fast). At least in this situation, it seems ok to have them as virtual. When I have more time, I run a lengthier test and see if the cost begins adding up. Thanks again.